# Check for duplicate values for a specific JSON key

Tags: json, parsing, duplicates, jq

I have the following JSON records stored in a container

```
    {"memberId":"123","city":"New York"}
    {"memberId":"234","city":"Chicago"}
    {"memberId":"345","city":"San Francisco"}
    {"memberId":"123","city":"New York"}
    {"memberId":"345","city":"San Francisco"}
```

I am looking to check if there is any duplication of the memberId - ideally return a true/false and then also return the duplicated values.

Desired Output:

```
true
123
345
```

Comment: Can you give your code ? and what is going wrong ?

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines - specifically, what output format are you expecting?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I did add a sample output

Answer (score 1):

Here's an efficient approach using `inputs`. It requires invoking jq with the -n command-line option.  The idea is to create a dictionary that keeps count of each memberId string value.

The dictionary can be created as follows:

```
reduce (inputs|.memberId|tostring) as $id ({}; .[$id] += 1)
```

Thus, to produce a true/false indicator, followed by the duplicates if any, you could write:

```
reduce (inputs|.memberId|tostring) as $id ({}; .[$id] += 1)
| to_entries
| map(select(.value > 1))
| (length > 0), .[].key
```

(If all the .memberId values are known to be strings, then of course the call to `tostring` can be dropped.  Conversely, if .memberId is both string and integer-valued, then the above program won't differentiate between occurrences of `1` and `"1"`, for example.)

### bow

The aforementioned dictionary is sometimes called a "bag of words" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model).  This leads to the generic function:

```
def bow(stream): 
  reduce stream as $word ({}; .[($word|tostring)] += 1);
```

The solution can now be written more concisely:

```
bow(inputs.memberId)
| to_entries
| map(select(.value > 1))
| (length > 0), .[].key
```

For just the values which have duplicates, one could write the more efficient query:

```
bow(inputs.memberId)
| keys_unsorted[] as $k
| select(.[$k] > 1)
| $k
```